Using jQuery Datepicker and dateFormat, altFormat and altField with $(this)
Using jQuery Datepicker, I can't get dateFormat, altFormat and altField to work correctly and output variables formatted as altFormat and using jQuery $(this)?
In the example below, the text input to the datepicker shows i.e., 20241218, while the console.logs shows i.e., Date Thu Dec 26 2024 00:00:00 GMT-0700. I'm trying to get the varibles startDate and endDate updated each time a date is selected by the user so that the variables in the format yymmdd can be used in a URL query string.
I realize that datepicker("option", "minDate", startDate) in the second and third function blocks seems to overwrite the options in the first function .datepicker({dateFormat: "MM dd, yy", altFormat: "yymmdd", altField: "#start_date_picker"}). But what I've tried throws Javascript errors.
The difference seems to have something to do with using $(this)this when generating the variables startDate and endDate in the second and third function blocks.
How can I use dateFormat, altFormat and altField so that they work? And output startDate and endDate in the format yymmdd?
https://jsfiddle.net/b302qwhd/
$(function() { 
            $("#start_date_picker")
            .datepicker({dateFormat: "MM dd, yy",
            altFormat: "yymmdd", altField: "#start_date_picker"});
            $("#end_date_picker")
            .datepicker({dateFormat: "MM dd, yy",
            altFormat: "yymmdd", altField: "#end_date_picker"});
            }); 

        $('#start_date_picker').on("change",function(){ 
            startDate = $(this).
            datepicker('getDate'); 
            $("#end_date_picker").
            datepicker("option", "minDate", startDate); 
            console.log(startDate);
        }) 

        $('#end_date_picker').on("change",function(){ 
            endDate = $(this).
            datepicker('getDate'); 
            $("#start_date_picker").
            datepicker("option", "maxDate", endDate); 
            console.log(endDate);

        });


The altField is not supposed to be another datepicker field, its just a field to have the value whenever it is updated in the original datepicker in the specified alternate format.
So you should have two additional fields to use as the altFields.


$(function() { 
    $("#start_date_picker").datepicker({dateFormat: "MM dd, yy",
            altFormat: "yymmdd", altField: "#start_alt"});
    $("#end_date_picker").datepicker({dateFormat: "MM dd, yy",
            altFormat: "yymmdd", altField: "#end_alt"});
}); 

$('#start_date_picker').on("change",function(){ 
    var sel = $(this).datepicker('option', 'altField'); 
    startDate = $(sel).val();
    $("#end_date_picker").datepicker("option", "minDate", $(this).datepicker('getDate')); 
    console.log(startDate);
}) 

$('#end_date_picker').on("change",function(){ 
    var sel = $(this).datepicker('option', 'altField'); 
    endDate = $(sel).val();
    $("#start_date_picker").
    datepicker("option", "maxDate", $(this).datepicker('getDate')); 
    console.log(endDate);

}) 
.ui-datepicker { 
    width: 12em;
 }
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.14.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

Start Date: <input type="text" id="start_date_picker">
End Date: <input type="text" id="end_date_picker">

<input type="hidden" id="start_alt">
<input type="hidden" id="end_alt">




Thanks! That works great. I didn't realize I needed the hidden fields, as well as your other changes. One additional point, which may or may not be complex: what would I need to do to get the two variables startDate and endDate available as variables outside the function and available to other Javascript on the page?

You don't really need the variables, you can access the values directly from the inputs $("#start_alt").val() and $("#end_alt").val()
